# How to access hard drive using terminal?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, hard-drive

I am new to Linux. I have installed Ubuntu distro. I would like to access the files on my internal hard drive using the terminal.

Can I use `cd` command to do so? Is there any other possible way using the terminal? (I want to learn to use the terminal)

Comment: Access how, do what exactly ? Is it your main hard drive or secondary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.
Anything that you can do in a windows shell/command line, you can also do in Ubuntu, although sometimes the commands are different, say, for example, to list directories, in Windows, you use `dir`, whereas in Unix based systems like Ubuntu, you use `ls`.

Here's a snippet from [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) of how the basic file and directory navigation commands:

> 1. The tilde (~) symbol stands for your home directory. If you are user, then the tilde (~) stands for /home/user
> 2. pwd: The pwd command will allow you to know in which directory you're located (pwd stands for "print working directory"). Example:
>      "pwd" in the Desktop directory will show "~/Desktop". Note that the
>      GNOME Terminal also displays this information in the title bar of its
>      window. A useful gnemonic is "present working directory."
> 3. ls: The ls command will show you ('list') the files in your current directory. Used with certain options, you can see sizes of files, when
>      files were made, and permissions of files. Example: "ls ~" will show
>      you the files that are in your home directory.
> 4. cd: The cd command will allow you to change directories. When you open a terminal you will be in your home directory. To move around the
>      file system you will use cd. Examples:
>
>    - To navigate into the root directory, use "cd /"
>    - To navigate to your home directory, use "cd" or "cd ~"
>    - To navigate up one directory level, use "cd .."
>    - To navigate to the previous directory (or back), use "cd -"
>    - To navigate through multiple levels of directory at once, specify the full directory path that you want to go to. For example, use, "cd
>        /var/www" to go directly to the /www subdirectory of /var/. As another
>        example, "cd ~/Desktop" will move you to the Desktop subdirectory
>        inside your home directory.
> 5. cp: The cp command will make a copy of a file for you. Example: "cp file foo" will make an exact copy of "file" and name it "foo", but the
>      file "file" will still be there. If you are copying a directory, you
>      must use "cp -r directory foo" (copy recursively). (To understand what
>      "recursively" means, think of it this way: to copy the directory and
>      all its files and subdirectories and all their files and
>      subdirectories of the subdirectories and all their files, and on and
>      on, "recursively")
> 6. mv: The mv command will move a file to a different location or will rename a file. Examples are as follows: "mv file foo" will rename the
>      file "file" to "foo". "mv foo ~/Desktop" will move the file "foo" to
>      your Desktop directory, but it will not rename it. You must specify a
>      new file name to rename a file.
>
>    - To save on typing, you can substitute '~' in place of the home directory.
>    - Note that if you are using mv with sudo you can use the ~ shortcut, because the terminal expands the ~ to your home directory. However,
>        when you open a root shell with sudo -i or sudo -s, ~ will refer to
>        the root account's home directory, not your own.
> 7. rm: Use this command to remove or delete a file in your directory.
> 8. rmdir: The rmdir command will delete an empty directory. To delete a directory and all of its contents recursively, use rm -r instead.
> 9. mkdir: The mkdir command will allow you to create directories. Example: "mkdir music" will create a directory called "music".
>
> Here is an example of when it would be necessary to execute a command
>   with administrative privileges. Let's suppose that another user has
>   accidentally moved one of your documents from your Documents directory
>   to the root directory. Normally, to move the document back, you would
>   type mv /mydoc.odt ~/Documents/mydoc.odt, but by default you are not
>   allowed to modify files outside your home directory. To get around
>   this, you would type sudo mv /mydoc.odt ~/Documents/mydoc.odt. This
>   will successfully move the document back to its correct location,
>   provided that you have administrative privileges.